# Does silicone rubber have a fundamental frequency?

Tags: elasticity

I'm wondering whether impulse excitation techniques may be used to derive the Young's Modulus and Poisson Ratio of Silicone rubber.

Comment: I suspect the damping would be very high with silicone rubber. Worth a try though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with John Rennie's comment, and also encourage you to try, but suspect a more effective means of excitation would be wide band random noise. In terms of dynamics you are looking at real valued eigenvalues. The trick will be deriving an analytical model that incorporates your moduli in terms of eigenvalues. You can then calculate the values from your system ID. But generally elastomeric materials tend to be nonlinear over large deformations. So dynamic testing, by any means of excitation may just lead to nonsense. Good luck